# >, <, <>, = Operators for Inner Join Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, subquery, inner-join

My boss threw this code my way and I am having a hard time understanding how the inner join's last ON statement works. I don't think he understands it completely either (but it gets the job done). Really just interested in learning more about how SQL works. Thank you so much!

Here is the On Statement

```
and (A.Submitted_Date > X.Submitted_Date)))
```

And here is the query

```
    SELECT AA.ID, AA.Submitted_Date as Date_Status      
    FROM Report as AA 
    where AA.Submitted_Date in
    --START
       (
        SELECT X.Submitted_Date
        FROM Report as A 
        inner join  
       --Start Find All Dates Submitted
        (
         SELECT [ID],[Submitted_Date]
         FROM Report
          where not(Submitted_Date is null and  Cleared_Date is null)
          group by ID, Submitted_Date) as X 
        --End Find all Dates  Submittd
     --below is the conditions of the join


    ON A.ID = X.ID 
    and A.ID= AA.ID

    --THIS IS THE CONDITION I AM CONFUSED ABOUT!!!!
    and (A.Submitted_Date > X.Submitted_Date)))

    group by X.Submitted_Date)

   and not AA.Submitted_Date is null 
   group by AA.ID, AA.Submitted_Date
```

Here is a Sample of Dates From Table A

```
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-12-10 00:00:00.000
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-29 00:00:00.000
2012-12-05 00:00:00.000
2012-12-12 00:00:00.000
```

Here is a Sample of Dates from Table X

```
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-29 00:00:00.000
2012-12-05 00:00:00.000
2012-12-10 00:00:00.000
2012-12-12 00:00:00.000
```

Here is the Result before The Last Condition

```
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-29 00:00:00.000
2012-12-05 00:00:00.000
2012-12-10 00:00:00.000
2012-12-12 00:00:00.000
```

Here is the result with A.Sub > X.Sub

```
2012-11-27 00:00:00.000
2012-11-29 00:00:00.000
2012-12-05 00:00:00.000
2012-12-10 00:00:00.000
```

I am confused on why those dates show up. What is being compared between A and X? Won't the values in A be the same as X always, therefore resulting in no final data? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think we need to know more about your Report table to answer this completely. Can you update your question so the sample data from X and A also has the Report.ID's. I have an idea of what is happening but i can't say without seeing the ID's as they're part of the join condition.

Comment: The resulting data is from one id. So think of this result set as having a where statement at the bottom where id = '111'; Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: IMHO it would be clearer if this condition was in WHERE clause. However, I'm not sure that the execution plan would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join condition is doing two things.  First, it is ensuring that `x.Submitted_Date` is not null.  This sort of directly contradicts the `whre` statement right above it.  In that statement, `Submitted_Date` could be NULL if `Cleared_Date` is not null.

The check for not NULL is simply by being used.  The join is an inner join, so only rows in `x` and `a` that match are retained.  When `x.Submitted_Date is null`, the comparison `A.Submitted_Date > X.Submitted_Date` evaluates to FALSE (actually NULL, but NULL is equivalent to FALSE in this context).

Second, it is ensuring that there is another record *later* in `Report` for a given `id`.  This is occurring through the same comparison:  `A.Submitted_Date > X.Submitted_Date` is saying that there is a later record in `A` than `X`.  The condition is true on all values of `Submitted_Date`, except for the maximum value.

So, in short, the conditions are taking all the submitted date values except for the latest date.

The condition may be equivalent to:

```
where AA.Submitted_Date <> (select MAX(x.Submitted_Date) from Report where x.id = AA.id)
```

I say *may* because the `Cleared_Date` makes this questionable.  But, I think they are the same.  The `where` clause in the original query is satisfied whenever `x.Submitted_Date` is not NULL.  The cleared date might bring in additional rows, but these would have null submitted date.  So, it is pulling all but the largest submitted date.

I would guess that the logic was once more complicated and this is a "simplified" version that could be simplified further.

Comment: Thank you for your response Gordon. Can you please elaborate on how it is checking to see if there is a record later? And how is it ensuring that x.submitted_date is not null? I feel like I am starting to have a better understanding!

Comment: I understand how it is getting rid of the last record.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Gordon! This makes things a lot clear. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Gordon why do we compare A.id with AA.id?

Comment: @KyleCopeland . . . That comparison is so you are only comparing dates for the id in a given row from the outer comparison.  This is called a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if your data would include the ID field. And I assume ID is not unique. Furthermore, I suspect your choice of sample is not ideal to understand the situation.

Considering these limitations on your question, I think what is confusing you is actually the condition A.ID = X.ID. This is what makes you think the dates would be the same and therefore there should be no data.

If you have Report table with:

```
1 2012-11-27
1 2012-11-29
```

then the cross join creates:

```
1 2012-11-27 1 2012-11-27
1 2012-11-27 1 2012-11-29
1 2012-11-29 1 2012-11-27
1 2012-11-29 1 2012-11-29
```

Which passes the criteria A.ID = X.ID and then A.date > X.date will return

```
1 2012-11-29 1 2012-11-27
```

edit: removed "Record 2012-11-27 should not be part of the result, based on the sample." because the date field being taken is from X, not from A.

Comment: This helps a lot thanks Koriander! That makes sense why he would Select x.SubDate